# Calling directive function from child directive not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to use a directive created by somebody else to tell my directive when the ngRepeat inside it has finished creating itself.

My outer directive has an isolate scope and has a scope function which needs to be called by the inner directive. Here is the code.

```
angular.module('my.directives')

.controller('myTableCtrl', function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

    $scope.tableLoaded = function(tableName){
        console.log("Table Loaded");
    };

})

.directive('myTable', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {},
        controller: 'myTableCtrl as myTable'
    };
})

.directive('repeatDone', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if (scope.$last) {
            $timeout(function(){
                scope.$eval(attrs.repeatDone);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

My HTML looks like this.

```
<my-table>
    <div ng-repeat="row in tableRows" repeat-done="tableLoaded('main');"></div>
</my-table>
```

Before I added the scope:{} to the myTable directive it was getting very confused when there were multiple tables on the page (the tableLoaded function was getting called but by the wrong child), so I added the isolate scope which I think is best practice. Unfortunately the repeatDone directive is now unable to see/call the tableLoaded() function in the parent myTable directive.

Any help would be really appreciated.

EDIT:

Just to clarify. tableLoaded() is a function of the myTable directive and I want to be able to call it from the repeatDone directive which could be however may elements deep inside the table directive. In addition to this I don't want to change the repeatDone directive and repeatDone wouldn't require or even be aware of the myTable directive.

Comment: Where where is tableRows being defined? It's not in any of the source code you posted.

Comment: That's in my main page controller. Also, I've simplified the table row template to just a div to make it easier to read. It's definitely working because the table gets filled with data and the tableLoaded() function gets called correctly when I remove the isolate scope from myTable.

Comment: @jonhobbs why do not use isolated scope and wire your function with '&' to inner directive?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, do you mean modify the repeatDone directive for this particular scenario? If so then that's not really an option. If you mean there's a way I can change the table directive so that the nested  repeatDone can call a function on it's scope then that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at the following solution. Hope this helps :)

```
    angular.module('my.directives')

    .controller('myTableCtrl', function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

    this.tableLoaded = function(tableName){    //bind the function to controller rather than $scope
        console.log("Table Loaded");
    };

    })

    .directive('myTable', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {},
        controller: 'myTableCtrl as myTable'
    };
})

.directive('repeatDone', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: true,  //your child directive might want to inherit stuff from the parent directive's controller maybe 
        require:'?^myTable',  //require the parent directive 
        link: function(scope, element, attrs,tableCtrl) {  //the controller of myTable is available as 4th param in link function (because of require)
            if (scope.$last) {
                $timeout(function(){
                    //scope.$eval(attrs.repeatDone);
                    tableCtrl.tableLoaded();    //call the function of the parent's directive (the specific instance)
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Edit:**

The issue I'm thinking of is the possibility of having multiple tables at once each having one repeatDone inside.
What you can do is, you can Emit an event on completion up the scope and catch it in your required controller/directive. Optionally, you can pass a unique identifier too so it catches only inside a particular controller/directive.
Here's the example:

```
.directive('repeatDone', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          console.log('in directive');
            var targetUID = attrs.target;
          console.log(targetUID);
            if (scope.$last) {
                $timeout(function(){

                  console.log('repeat-done now');//scope.$eval(attrs.repeatDone);
                    scope.$emit('repeat-done-' + targetUID,{});
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

in your table directive:

```
.directive('myTable', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        controller: 'myTableCtrl as myTable'
    };
})
```

and in your table controller:

```
.controller('myTableCtrl', function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    console.log('in table Ctrl');
            var self = this;
            $scope.tableUID = $attrs.tableId;
            self.tableLoaded = function(){
                console.log("Table Loaded");
            };
            console.log('tableUID' + $scope.tableUID);
            $scope.$on('repeat-done-' + $scope.tableUID, function(event,args){
              console.log('in catcher function');
                self.tableLoaded();
            });
})
```

then use

```
<my-table table-id="table1">
    <div ng-repeat="row in tableRows" repeat-done target="table1"></div>
</my-table>
```

Here's a working [JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/yozifatiju/edit?html,js,console,output)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you Ahsan, but repeat-done should be a generic directive which can be used on any repeat to call a function somewhere higher up the scope chain. It shouldn't know about myTable

Comment: Can you confirm that it can be "somewhere higher up the scope chain" or just the immediate parent scope?

Comment: The repeat-done could be any number of scopes deep inside my table, but only the table directive will have a tableLoaded() function.

Comment: @jonhobbs Edited my response with a working example link, do check

Comment: Thanks Ahsan, directive coupling and emittng events are two things that I wanted to avoid. I thought it could just be done by using the scope chain because the repeatDone is a child of the table, but after some research it seems as if isolate scopes don't just isolate themselves from their parents, they completely remove themselves from the scope chain. So it seems your suggestions are my only two options. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to use ng-transclude on `my-table` to be able to use inner elements

Comment: That doesn't work because I'm not applying a template to the directive so it has nowhere to be transcluded to.

Comment: And you are using controllerAs as well. Shouldn't you bind your method to `this` instead of `$scope` ?

Comment: I'm not sure. Usually my methods go on the scope.